# Apache chemistry querying a folder

Tags: apache, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am using Apache chemistry to write and read data from a content management system in a Java servlet. I am currently creating a separate folder for each logged on user in the CMS. When the user logs on I have to check and get the reference of the user's Folder so that I can use the same in the session. When the folder is created for the first time, I can get the user's folder using the createFolder call:

```
    Folder userFolder = root.createFolder(newFolderProps);
```

However if the folder already exists, the only way I can get the folder is by Iterating throught all the children. This can be pretty inefficient. I was wondering if there is any way of specifying the folder name as a query parameter so that I can directly get the users folder without iterating over all the child folders.

Answer (score 6):

Try getObject() or getObjectByPath():

```
Folder userFolder = (Folder) session.getObject(folderId);
Folder userFolder = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath(folderPath);
```